# Apple In app purchase receipt in wrong format

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm validating my receipts against the Appstore, following the Apple's guide. The receipt is retrieved from the bundle using  the following code:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
NSString *base64Receipt = [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

The encoded receipt is a signed binary file, as described in the documentation. However, in some weird cases the receipt is not the expected binary file but a NSDictionary with the form

```
{
 pod = 50;
 "purchase-info" = "ewo...";
 signature = "Apdx...";
 "signing-status" = 0;
}
```

When I try to validate those receipts against the AppStore, the result is always 21002 ("The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing"). Any ideas in why the receipt retrieved from the bundle is in the wrong format?

Comment: Please give the complete code fragment, including NSLog or other output. Have you submitted a bug report to Apple?

Comment: Hi, after our research we notice that the receipt is in iOS6 format. Our app is for iOS7+ so it seems that some users are using jailbreak iPhones to try to cheat our purchase system. So, our validation process was working correctly and was blocking those purchases.